# Calling void function arduino

Tags: arduino

I have written the following code:

```
void dice (int &x) {
   for (int i = 0;i<7;i++){
       delay (35);

       int kocka;
       kocka = random (1,7);

       randomSeed (analogRead (A7));
       delay(5); 
   }
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(dice(int x));
};
```

However when I try to compile it, I get this error:

> expected primary-expression before 'int'

Comment: I can't call my void functions, I am new here and in the programming world.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a void function, but for the argument you pass you don't put "int".  You know this if you think about it, when you write a digitalWrite do you put "int" in front of the pin number?  You only need the int when you are writing the function prototype.

You also don't have any variable x defined to pass to that function, so your next error is "x not declared in this scope" since in the loop function there is no x variable.

You have another problem lurking next.  Your function is defined to return void.  That means it returns nothing.  And sure enough, there is no return statement.  So when you remove the "int" in the Serial.print line, and define a variable x, you will get a "void value not ignored" error.  You can't print the return value from a function that has no return value.

It isn't really clear what you want that to print out.  Edit your question to say what you want to happen and maybe someone can help you figure out how to do it.